# What purpose does C:\USERS\%username%\Tracing\WPPMedia serve?

Tags: windows, skype, user-folders

What purpose do the `C:\USERS\%username%\Tracing\WPPMedia\*.*` folder and files serve? It appears to be related to *Skype* and potentially *Windows Live Messenger* according to random forum posts. Also curious what *WPPMedia* is.

Mine has the following files:

- Skype_MediaStack-6.0.8878.0-lcsmedia_vnext_release3(rtbldlab)-x86fre-U.etl
- Skype_MediaStack-6.0.8878.0-lcsmedia_vnext_release3(rtbldlab)-x86fre-U.etl.bak
- Skype_MediaStack-6.0.8885.7-lcsmedia_vnext_release4(rtbldlab)-x86fre-U.etl
- Skype_MediaStackETW-6.0.8878.0-lcsmedia_vnext_release3(rtbldlab)-x86fre-U.etl
- Skype_MediaStackETW-6.0.8878.0-lcsmedia_vnext_release3(rtbldlab)-x86fre-U.etl.bak
- Skype_MediaStackETW-6.0.8885.7-lcsmedia_vnext_release4(rtbldlab)-x86fre-U.etl

Answer (score 11):

Everything under `%username%\Tracing` seems to be diagnostic logging and debugging data created by apps that use the [Unified Communications Client API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878897.aspx), such as [Office Communicator/Lync, Windows Live Messenger](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/871023/), Skype etc.

Event Trace Log (ETL) files can be viewed using the Event Viewer among other tools. The WPP in WPPMedia refers to the [Windows software trace preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_software_trace_preprocessor) used for logging and debugging.

Comment: Is there any way to remove them?

Comment: If not while Windows is running they can definitely be deleted via a LiveCD or perhaps even in Safe Mode. Question is, will the programs involved complain or break, and even if they don't, will they not continue to create more such files? I have not investigated any of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `.etl` extension usually refers to Event Trace Log files. My guess would be that it contains data for debugging purposes. If you would like to see what is in the files you can open them via the Event Viewer built into Windows.