# How do I prevent the creation of %Userprofile%\Tracing?

Tags: windows-10, skype

I use Skype. Not a lot, but frequently enough. This folder `C:\Users\%username%\Tracing` is created every time I open Skype. Alternatively seen in Registry editor as `%Userprofile%\Tracing\WPPMedia`

I want to stop this behaviour.
How do I prevent the creation of `C:\Users\%username%\Tracing`?

Found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/901580/what-purpose-does-c-users-username-tracing-wppmedia-serve) on SuperUser on what Tracing folder is. & [this discussion](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/skype-7-1-keeps-making-a-Tracing-file-im-my-docs/td-p/3857174) on how to stop it (didn't try the solutions mentioned there because it talks about windows 7, while I use windows 10 & the file names mentioned there are not the same as mine. Plus, feels unreliable.)

**Edit**: Attempted to change registry values for "EnableTracing", but it’s already "00000000" & the folder creation behaviour persists. Moving the folder to `%temp%` folder doesn’t solve the problem. I would just have to go to `%temp%` to delete manually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The registry edit should still work on Windows 10. Change the path to your Temp-Folder and disable tracing:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Tracing\WPPMediaPerApp\Skype]
"WPPFilePath"="%TEMP%\Tracing\WPPMedia"
"EnableTracing"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Tracing\WPPMediaPerApp\Skype\ETW]
"WPPFilePath"="%TEMP%\Tracing\WPPMedia"
"EnableTracing"=dword:00000000

Comment: the folder is still being created. Now, its in %TEMP% folder, and its even more annoying to delete because I have to navigate to %TEMP% folder